# Что он для неё не/ни делал, а она всё равно его избегала

Tags: орфография

*Не* или *ни* надо?

> Что он для неё не/ни делал, а она всё равно его избегала.

> Что он для неё не/ни делал, она всё равно его избегала.

> Как я тольно не/ни пытался ей помочь, как только не/ни пытался ее поддержать, сколько хороших, тёплых слов в ненастные минуты не/ни говорит, а она всё же меня ненавидела.

> Как я тольно не/ни пытался ей помочь, как только не/ни пытался ее поддержать, сколько хороших, тёплых слов в ненастные минуты не/ни говорит, — она всё же меня ненавидела.